# how to restrict Yii2 url view get request

Tags: url, yii2

Here I like to explain my problem clearly, How can I restrict get request through URL in Yii2

this is my url:

`http://localhost/school/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fview&id=42`

here if I change the `view id = 43`, it showing the data of `id` `43`, I don't want to get data through url. I want to restrict get request through url `or` how can I encrypt the `id` value

If I change my url manager to

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
     'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

then am getting url like below

`http://localhost/school/admin/user/view?id=42`

here also if I change `id=43` am getting the data of `id` `43`

How can I do this. Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: what is the id in your example? The current user's id? Or another id that the current user have access to? If is another one, how do you know which user have access to who? That information is beeing saved and how? Can you update your question with this informations?

Comment: unique id for user @Clyff

Comment: Actually i have login for manager(user_type is manager). this login is used to add employees alone, not to see other company employee details. but they changing id in url, and they getting data. how can i restrict that  @Clyff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming the current scenario (let me know if i misunderstood something):**

`Company` can see/add/edit `People` (that part you already did). Now, each `Company` can only do actions on your own `People`, not the others.

**One Solution:**

In your `Company` model you must have something like:

```
public function getPeoples()
{
    return $this->hasMany(People::className(), ['id_people' => 'id']);
}
```

You can add another function just to return the Ids of the `People`:

```
public function getPeoplesIds()
{
    return ArrayHelper::map($this->peoples, 'id', 'id');
}
```

Now in your controler you must rewrite your `beforeAction` function:

```
public function beforeAction($action){
    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');

    if($id && !Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->getId());
        $company = //Do the logic to get the company's user

        if (! in_array($id, $company->peoplesIds) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

With that, you are checking the `$id` before runing each action.

Comment: what i need to write in $company="", I didnt get what you trying say

Comment: In which controller i need to write this controller code, **people or user or company**

Comment: The controller which have the actions you want to restrict. In my example would be `People`. About your question... well I assumed everyone need to login before do any stuff right? So you have the current `User`. Now you need to copy your logic you used to associate `Users` to, in my example, `Company`. If my example is too different of what you have at the moment, please update your question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should think about your purpose .
why do you want to prevent user from getting another IDs ?
if they are not authorized to see other IDs you can easily authorize their requests : [Yii2-authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)

otherwise , you can use a string key for your table and generate random strings for keys using Yii built in classes .
[Yii2-security](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html)

Comment: Actually i have login for manager(user_type is manager). this login is used to add employees alone, not to see other company employee details. but they changing id in url, and they getting data. how can i restrict that

Comment: when user is login , he or she is authenticated to access resources , but after authentication we suppose to check which authenticated user is able to access which resource , now we face another definition Authorization . you can learn how to authorize users in yii2 documentation easily ( not really easily ) using authorization link in my answer